# Add Button to DropDown Menu

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm using the standard Drupal dropdown menu module and I want to add a call-to-action button under the menu items.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by saying the standard 'Drupal dropdown menu' module? There is only the core 'menu' module. Can you provide a screenshot? Which is the dropdown menus you want to add a call-to-action?